# relax, jack song

Tags: history

Anyone know the title of the song with a refrain like " Relax, jack. It's just a simple fact, Jack"?

The recording I recall is ~50 years old and was sung by a black woman, maybe Eartha Kitt.

I realize this may not be the proper community for this question. Guidance appreciated.

Comment: This question would be more suitable for musicfans SE site.

Comment: @user1079505 Identification questions are off topic on musicfans.

Comment: What is the suitable SE site?  I've seen identification questions, usually re books or movies on SE sites.  Nothing for songs?

Comment: @shanebp Currently there is no site accommodating song identification questions; however, you have enough reputation to post in the chat room, where the question would be appropriate and welcome.